# batch within batch call directories and jumping between labels

Tags: batch-file, menu, path, directory, call

I have a .bat that is a large menu with multiple options.

Each option calls upon a different batch file that is located in the same directory under the subfolder "/scripts".

I've made each individual script universal by removing any directory paths. How does one send the direction of where those scripts should do their work within the main menu script?

---

OK here is some code.

This is a small version of my main.bat

```
@echo off
cls
SET "scriptdir=z:\scripts"
SET "workdir=c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test"

:start
echo Clean And Rename Test V2.0.1
echo.
echo 1. Root Directory Only
echo 2. Root And Subfolders
echo.
echo 3. None, Exit...
echo.
set /p menu0=...1,2,3?
if '%menu0%'=='1' CALL :root.only
if '%menu0%'=='2' CALL :root.only&CALL:root.with.subs
if '%menu0%'=='3' CALL :end2
goto start

:root.only
echo Deleting Junk Files
CALL %scriptdir%\01-test-root-delete-junk.bat %workdir%
echo.
echo Cleaning File Names
CALL %scriptdir%\02-test-root-clean-names.bat %workdir%
echo.
echo Setting Letter Case
CALL %scriptdir%\03-test-root-letter-case.bat %workdir%
echo.
goto :end

:root.with.subs
echo Deleting Junk Files
CALL %scriptdir%\10-test-subs-delete-junk.bat %workdir%
echo.
echo Cleaning File Names
CALL %scriptdir%\11-test-subs-clean-names.bat %workdir%
echo.
echo Setting Letter Case
CALL %scriptdir%\12-test-subs-letter-case-.bat %workdir%
echo.
goto :end

:end
echo Actions Complete
echo.
pause
exit

:end2
exit
```

And here is one of the scripts.

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "%~dp0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Cleanup Dots/Underscores
for %%j in (*.*) do (
   set filename=%%~nj
      set filename=!filename:.= !
      set filename=!filename:_= !
      set filename=!filename:[=!
      set filename=!filename:]=!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)

REM Set All To Lowercase
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set "filename=%%~Nf"
   for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%a=%%a!"
   )

REM Set Very First To Uppercase   
   set "letter=!filename:~0,1!"
for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "letter=!letter:%%A=%%A!"
   )
   ren "%%f" "!letter!!filename:~1!%%~Xf"
)

REM Setting Title Case
for %%j in (*.*) do (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename: a= A!
set filename=!filename: b= B!
set filename=!filename: c= C!
set filename=!filename: d= D!
set filename=!filename: e= E!
set filename=!filename: f= F!
set filename=!filename: g= G!
set filename=!filename: h= H!
set filename=!filename: i= I!
set filename=!filename: j= J!
set filename=!filename: k= K!
set filename=!filename: l= L!
set filename=!filename: m= M!
set filename=!filename: n= N!
set filename=!filename: o= O!
set filename=!filename: p= P!
set filename=!filename: q= Q!
set filename=!filename: r= R!
set filename=!filename: s= S!
set filename=!filename: t= T!
set filename=!filename: u= U!
set filename=!filename: v= V!
set filename=!filename: w= W!
set filename=!filename: x= X!
set filename=!filename: y= Y!
set filename=!filename: z= Z!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
popd
```

Basically what I would like to do put all the scripts in z:\scripts.  Then have multiple versions of my main.bat that I put in various places.  I'll be renaming the main.bat for it's particular task, I want the main.bat to call upon the scripts and tell them where to work, and sequentially if need be.

I've used a bat to exe compiler which is nice makes it work great, maybe useful much later at the end of everything when done editing and building.

I'm a newb.  My desire to do it this way for now is learning and organization.  I want to write a script and know that it works perfect and store it.  While doing all the work in the main file for controlling things.  That way if something goes wrong I know it has to do with the main file and not something that could also have accidentally gone wrong in the hundreds of lines of scripts.
Thoughts?

Comment: tried a few more things to no avail.  just a little confused about this part.

Comment: I've commented my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of the individual Batch files may set the directory it needs to work via this command:

```
cd "%~dp0"
```

... or use a variable similar to "sourcedir" one in the menu Batch file set in the same way.

If the individual Batch files have a `setlocal` command, just put previous line after it and that is it. The directory will be automatically reset to the original one when each individual file ends.

If the Batch files have not a `setlocal` command, you may set the directory at beginning with

```
pushd "%~dp0"
```

... and reset the original directory before end using

```
popd
```

This way you don't need to modify the main Batch file and the individual files may be placed in any directory; for example, in a directory included in `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call your bat files and pass the path to the target directory:

In your main bat:

```
...
call sub-bat.bat c:\folder\subfolder\folderToDoWorkIn\
...
```

In your sub-bat:

```
...
SET targetFolder=%1
...
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  That works but only for the first bat script.  The only way I've been able to get them to run sequentially is if I put all the files in the working folder and delete paths from every file.

Comment: I don't get it. You are passing `%workdir%` to your bat files but inside your called bats you are doing `PUSHD "%~dp0"`? You should replace that by `CD %workdir%`. By the way, wehn you start a sub-bat file using `CALL` (you could also use `START` but then this wouldn't work) your called bats have full access to any variable set in your main bat. So if you do `SET workdir=c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test` in your main bat you don't have to pass this variable to other bats called with `CALL`. You can just use it as `%workdir%` inside your sub-bats.

Comment: Brilliant, it totally works. haha something so simple.  Thanks man :D